# Simplest Way To Deploy Javascript Application On Linux

Tags: javascript, python, linux, web-deployment, putty

I have an folder say 'mywebapp' on windows machines. This folder has index.html page, js directory with java script files and css directory with css files.

Now when i open this index.html into browser, the browser displays contents pretty well, as if i have deployed this application on server, which is not the case.

Now i wanted to do same on my Linux machine vm, login-ed through putty. I tried using pythons SimpleHTTPServer which gave me same result. But as soon as i exit from putty session, the webpage doesnt display. seems like SimpleHTTPServer server connection is broken once i exit the putty session.
 Please help me.
 Or any other professional and easy way to get my webpage displayed. Tomcat seems good option but i don't have root permission and don't want hectic deployment process.
I heard about node.js, but i don't have root permission to install node.

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way i can suggest it to download and copy tar.gz file from location:

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

1 then gunzip and untar this downloaded file.

2 Go to conf/Catelina/localhost folder.

3 create an xml with your application name, e.g. mywebapp.xml
and put following to this file:

```
<Context path="/mywebapp" reloadable="false" docBase="<root-path of your application folder>"/>
```

here "root-path of your application folder" will be the root folder of ypur HTML, js and css files.
Then just start this tomcat using /bin/startup.sh command and check on browser using localhost:8080/mywebapp

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But i don't see conf/Catelina/localhost/ folder in my untar directory